# Mocking Static methods with a class with constructor restricted

Tags: static, mockito, powermockito

I am encountering issue while performing mocking and when I run it as static class, it throwing error

```
public class UtilClass {

   private UtilClass() throws InstantiationException {
      // should never be called. 
      throw new InstantiationException("Instances of UtilClassare forbidden.");
   }

   public static void getData() {
      sysout("Testing");
   }
}
```

Test Case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(UtilClass.class)

public class UtilTest{

@InjectMocks
private UtilClass objectUnderTest;
 @Before
    public void preTest()
            throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilClass.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData() {
    //assert statements
    }

}
```

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'objectUnderTest' of type 'class UtilClass'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Instances of UtilClassare forbidden.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense for 2 reasons. First: you're trying to create an instance of the class, although what you want to test is a **static** method, which doesn't need any instance, and although the class has a private constructor precisely to prevent you from doing that mistake of creating useless instances. Second: you're mocking (i.e. replacing by a fake implementation) the static method that you want to test. So if you call the method, you will actually test nothing at all. You should read about static methods, and about mocks.

Comment: Mocks are used to create fake **dependencies** of the class under test. I.e. if you want to test A, and A uses B, you mock B. Not A.